# Comodo dragon gives me warning about certificates installed on my system

Tags: certificates

today I was surfing the web with Comodo dragon browser and it gave me this warning:
[image]

it don't tell me which certificate! is there any tool that I can use to scan my installed certificates?
and also because I'm living in Iran and websites like youtube are filtered by government I use vpn to bypass this filtering. is it possible that vpn be the reason of this message?

Comment: it's possible your VPN uses it's own cert, not a "trusted" one.  Which, strangely enough, is actually more secure.  I believe this page shows how to view your installed certs:  https://www.comodo.com/support/products/authentication_certs/setup/dragon.php?af=7639

Comment: 'being monitored' ... g00gle anyone ?

Answer (score 1):

I just used another Comodo's product to scan my PC and find out this warning was a false positive about "microsoft ecc development root certificate authority 2018".
but anyway if you need to scan your installed certificate just like me you can use comodo free antivirus
[image]

Update:
Because I wanted to investigate more about this issue, as described in this [article](https://www.nextofwindows.com/scanning-windows-certificate-store-for-suspicious-certificates) by Kent Chen I used [sigcheck](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sigcheck) to list all my suspicious certificates. it was so much better than antivirus and showed me more certificates which I should consider for examining.
just download the sigcheck, unzip it and open PowerShell in that directory and execute following command

```
 .\sigcheck -tv
```